# Open .txt attachment from email in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've defined an `intent-filter` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` so that it should show my app as an option to open text files:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Hosts.AddHostActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_add_host" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then I'm going to handle the opening of the text file like this:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
if(data != null) {
    // Parse text file
}
```

Although I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about it. Currently my app does not show in the list of apps that can open text files though so I assume something in my `intent-filter` definition is wrong?

I've updated my intent filter to change the `mimeType` and add `BROWSABLE` but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Turns out mimeType is the best way to go and you don't need the other junk :)